# How to apply if else in css based on ionic app build type?

Tags: html, css, ionic4

I'm create simple ionic 4 app, and i'm use some css for android as well as ios. now when i'm build ios, android css conflicted. i want to if/else condition in css based on build type ?

Comment: https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to write `if-else` for switching between css classes for platform-specific css.

There is method in ionic 4 for platform-specific css's.

for android platform write your css like this :
`md` because android, as well as other, platforms, use material design by default.

```
.md .sample {}
```

and while using IOS platform :

```
.ios .sample {}
```

here are [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-styles) for more info.

Comment: Thank you sir,You are great.

Comment: glad to help! :-)